# I need help converting a string to an integer

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, integer, android-arrayadapter, parseint

Good day,
I have an array adapter in Activity1 in my AndroidStudio project. I would like to transfer two specific items from the ArrayAdapter (in positions 1 and 2) to Activity2 with an intent. (the ArrayAdapter is connected to an editTextNumber) That works well if I then display the two items in a TextView. But if I want to convert the items to an int, the app always crashes. I can somehow just convert "message1" into an int. Why is that so?
Thank you for your help

(Activity 1):
[...]

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ArrayAdapter adapterzeit = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, zeit1);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE1", adapterzeit.getItem(1).toString());
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE2", adapterzeit.getItem(3).toString());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
}
```

(Activity 2):

```
[...]
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String message1 = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE1");
        String message2 = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE2");

        int numberInt = Integer.parseInt(message1);
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(message2);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please add the crash log to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You add the extra to the `Intent` like this:

```
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE1", adapterzeit.getItem(1).toString());
```

and then you try to extract it from the `Intent` like this:

```
String message1 = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
```

You are using different String values for the keys! `EXTRA_MESSAGE != EXTRA_MESSAGE1`

This is one reason why you should always use **constant definitions** for these kinds of things, then you wouldn't have this problem. For example, in `Activity1`:

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE1 = "EXTRA_MESSAGE1";

intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, adapterzeit.getItem(1).toString());
```

and then in `Activity2`:

```
String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(Activity1.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
```

Comment: Good day,
Thank you for your reply. I changed the names of the "extra-messages" for the question (and I forgot to change both to "EXTRA_MESSAGE1"). In my project both have the same name. So that's not the problem. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: OK, then edit your question and post the exception messages from logcat and we can see what the problem is.